# Cocoa Immutable CheckBox

Tags: swift, cocoa, checkbox

I have a window that is displaying some info about a file - including whether it's a package or an alias. I'm currently using a checkbox, but since you can't set those values, I don't want the checkbox to be editable. I know I can set it to disabled, but I don't actually want it disabled. Is there a way to just make it immutable in the UI or a better control that I could use to display that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make a subclass and override `mouseDown` event like this:

```
class CustomCheckBox: NSButton {

    @IBInspectable var editable : Bool = true

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if editable {
            super.mouseDown(with: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i went with a little simpler version that doesn't have an inspectable and just swallows the mouse down event. thanks!

Comment: Yep, `@IBInspectable` is totally optional, for handy customization in Interface Builder.